# Do I need to import smslib into eclipse to start using it?

Tags: java, smslib

I have done all the installation in order to use smslib. the part that I don't get is what should I do to the smslib.zip that I downloaded? How I can use this library...

Comment: I'm guessing the zip should be unzipped. And did you follow the installation instructions?

Comment: Yes sir I unzipped it already...

Answer (score 0):

For building and application you may follow the [link](http://codexamples.blogspot.in/2011/05/java-sms-send-read-with-smslib.html) and to add the jar into your project, **right click on the project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Library -> User Library -> next -> User Libraries -> new -> Add external jars** then add the required smslib jars.

Comment: I see.. Thank you Sir subhashis... so only jar files are needed for me to use the smslib? I only need to add those jars into my project?